# How to generate word document with a datasource?

Tags: c#, xsd, ms-word, vsto

I want to populate a Word Document template with a runtime datasource (object instance). I read a lot about Word Schema, XML, XSD etc. but everything is still very fuzzy and difficult to understand the different terminologies.

I followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6007a1wt.aspx) but I don't know where to get a word schema to add to the word document or schema library.

Within Visual Studio 2010, I also managed finished the steps for Document-Level Projects by drag and drop the datasource (object) to [create the content controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97h3yd8w.aspx), but I don't know what to do after that. How can I use the word document at runtime with binded object data and open an instance of the word document for editing/printing?

Answer (score 1):

> Thankfully, the open source DocX by Cathal Coffey solves both problems
>   nicely, and unlike Interop, presents an easy-to-use, highly
>   discoverable API for performing myriad manipulations/extractions
>   against the Word document format (the .docx format, introduced as of
>   Word 2007). Best of all, DocX does not require that Word or any other
>   Office dependencies be installed on the client machine! The full
>   source is available from Coffey's Codeplex repo, or you can add DocX
>   to your project using Nuget.

Source: [Writing to Word Doc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra)

Comment: Seems like it does not handle content controls?

Answer (score 0):

Content controls support binding only with [custom xml part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608618.aspx).

So first add your XML as customxml part of the doucment.

```
Office.CustomXMLPart employeeXMLPart = this.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlData);//xmlData is xml string
```

Then bind the content control with the xpath

```
string xPathName = "ns:employees/ns:employee/ns:name";
    this.plainTextContentControl1.XMLMapping.SetMapping(xPathName,
        prefix, employeeXMLPart);
```

[Here is the reference article from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398244.aspx)